# handling not null for optional fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table, check-constraints, sql-null

Lets say that the frontend has an input form for user registration. A user can signup by either full name or company name. What would be the best approach for handling null data type in this scenario? Should the data type be `NOT NULL` with a default value of something? It could be the case that not every user will use both the full name and company name together when registering.

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
    company_name VARCHAR(255),
    full_name VARCHAR(255)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` is usually the way to represent the absence of data; in the scenario you describe, it does not look like using a default value would help.

Then: columns are nullable by default. If you want to enforce a rule that at least one the two columns should be not null, you can use a check constraint. Adding a serial primary key to the table would also be a good idea.

```
create table customer(
    customer_id serial primary key,
    company_name varchar(255),
    full_name varchar(255),
    check (company_name is not null or full_name is not null)
);
```

Comment: worked perfectly. I was unaware of the check constraint. thanks for this suggestion!

Comment: I actually think that an empty string would be better there, but it is a matter of taste.